# Is "would" possible in the first conditional?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> "If I *give* you money, **would** you go and get me some fruit?" (*Seinfeld*)

As I know *would* is not used in either zero or first conditionals. I would not have noticed that if it'd been *will*. Can you justify *would* in here, or it is just the spoken English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *would*, although it appears in a conditional, is not used in the ordinary predictive sense but in a "volitive" sense fossilized from the original meaning of *will* = *want*, *desire*, *be willing*.

This survives mostly as a "past subjunctive" in such polite questions as your example, where it means, approximately, "please", and in earnest wishes such as

> If he would only listen to me!  .. *that is*, "I wish he were willing to listen."

It does survive in present-tense form as well in such "negotiating" constructions as this:

> If you'll find me the saw I'll cut that for you.

*Will* in the condition clause marks this as a different sense than your ordinary "first conditional".

Comment: I'd say this is a borderline http://english.stackechange.com/ type answer :)

Comment: "If I give you money, go and get me some fruit?" is a direct imperative statement. Instead of it, you could use a polite request with 'would you..?'.

Comment: @JayHook: I don't know about that. It sounds like a somewhat confusing mixture of tense/mood/conditionality to me. Maybe a sort of shorthand way of saying *"If I give you money, **then you must** go and get me some fruit"* (but if I *don't* give you money, you can ignore what I just said).

Comment: @JayHook What FF says. Imperative is "Here's some money, go get me some fruit."

Comment: This strikes me as a short form of "If I give you money, would you mind going and getting me some fruit?"

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that you mean that the given sentence is a more-or-less acceptable variant of "If I gave you money, would you go and get me some fruit?"? Or are you implying some other reasons too for its acceptability?